# How to call Wildfly Transaction Manager in Java Code?

Tags: java, wildfly, jta, wildfly-16

What should be name of default transaction manager in wildlfy to be used in Java code.

Following is wildfly screen and i am not getting anyname here:

[image]

I am not getting any code related to same following is thing i am trying from codegeeks:

```
public static final String JBOSS_USER_TRANSACTION = "java:jboss/UserTransaction"; // ????

public static final String JBOSS_TRANSACTION_MANANGER = "java:jboss/TransactionManager"; // ???

JtaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setTransactionManagerName(JtaTransactionManager.DEFAULT_USER_TRANSACTION_NAME);
        final PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager = transactionManager;
```

Comment: You don't need the names if you inject it. Why don't you inject the references? And why do you need the transaction manager?